# Enviar datos desde un form a un Action usando struts2, AJAX, y jquery dialog

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, diálogo

Buenas, estoy intentando recoger el contenido de un formulario a un Action, pero siempre obtengo **null**. 
Lo que he realizado es:
**JSP:**

```
<s:div id="popup-usuarios">
  <s:form name="formEditar" id ="dForm" method="post">
    <s:textarea id="data" name="data" class="data" rows="4" cols="100" />
  </s:form> 
</s:div>
```

**JS:**

```
/** Definición del dialog que presenta los datos de edición del usuario. */
$("#popup-usuarios").dialog({
    width : 'auto',
    minWidth: 500,
    autoOpen : false,
    modal : true,
    zIndex: 500,
    title: "Datos Usuario", 
    open : function() {
    $("#dialog").css('overflow', 'hidden');
    },
    buttons : {
        Cancelar : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Aceptar : function() {
            peticionAjaxEditarUsuario("#formEditar","editarUsuarioAction","#contenidAdministracion");
        }
    }
});
```

**Llamada AJAX:**

```
function peticionAjaxEditarUsuario(idForm, urlAction, idDiv){
var dataForm = $(idForm).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlAction,
    data: dataForm,
    error : function(data) {

    },
    success : function(data) {
        $('#popup-usuarios').dialog('close');
        $('#popup-usuarios').dialog('destroy').remove();
        // Volcado de la respuesta en el div.
        $(idDiv).html(data);        

    }
});
```

**STRUTS.XML:**

```
<!-- Acción de edición de los datos de un usuario. -->
    <action name="editarUsuarioAction" method="editarItemUsuario" class="com.iecisa.tecdoc.sirene.db.action.SireneUsersAction">
        <result name="success">/administracion.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

**ACTION:**

```
 String data;
public String getData() {
     return data;
```

}

```
public String editarItemUsuario(){
    System.out.println("data:"+getData());
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

El **getData** me está devolviendo **null**.
Alguna idea? He probado bastantes cosas e investigado pero no doy con la solución.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:form name="formEditar" id ="dForm" method="post">

....
var dataForm = $(idForm).serialize(); //idForm debería valer "#formEditar" aquí
```

De la documentación JQuery ([selectors-basic](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)); las negritas las he puesto yo:

> ID Selector (“#id”)
>
> Selects a single element with the given **id** attribute.

Le estás pasando el valor del atributo `name`, tendrías que pasarle el valor del atributo `id` del form (cuidado que parece que falta una `i`, ya que tienes `id="dForm"`).

En todo caso, puedes revisar con `alerts` o `console.log` para ver exáctamente qué objetos usas, y usar la pestaña de Red/Network de navegador para ver qué peticiones pasas y con qué datos.

Comment: Gracias!! estaba cogiendo el _name_ como bien has dicho, además de la **i** que  como bien has mencionado, faltaba.
Lo que no entiendo es el por qué estaba cogiéndome el _name_ en vez del _id_. ¿Es porque le estaba pasando un id incorrecto? Aún así le echaré un vistazo a la documentación que me has proporcionado.
De nuevo muchas gracias!